# Using mpdf html + php

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm new to programming and I've been trying to make a pdf with mpdf, but it's been a bit more complicated than I thought. I have already built some variables but joining them together is complicated, in a few words they wanted to put this table that contains mpdf and php in a pdf

this is the table:

```
        <table id="Liderazgo">
            <caption class ="titulos">Liderazgo</caption>
            <tr id="lid">
                <?php $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                    foreach($obj as $data){ 
                        if($data['llave'] == 'Visionario'){ ?>
                        <td class ="Visionario" width="51" height="27">
                        <?php for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++){
                        echo '&#9733'; } ?></td> <?php 
                        }
                        }
                        ?>

                <?php $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                    foreach($obj as $data){ 
                        if($data['llave'] == 'Protector'){  ?>
                        <td class ="Protector" width="51" height="27">
                        <?php for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++){
                        echo '&#9733'; } ?></td> <?php 
                        }
                        }
                        ?>

                <?php $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                    foreach($obj as $data){ 
                        if($data['llave'] == 'Participativo'){  ?>
                        <td class ="Participativo" width="51" height="27">
                        <?php for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++){
                        echo '&#9733'; } ?></td> <?php 
                        }
                        }
                        ?>



            </tr>
            <Tr class = "texto">
                <Td width="48" height="15">Visionario</Td>
                <Td width="48" height="15">Protector</Td>
                <Td width="48" height="15">Participativo</Td>

            </Tr>
            </table>
```

and this is the mpdf i created:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
            'mode' => 'utf-8',
            'format' => 'A4',
            'default_font' => 'mycustomfont',
            'margin_left' => 15,
            'margin_right' => 10,
            'margin_top' => 16,
            'margin_bottom' => 10,
            'margin_header' => 10,
            'margin_footer' => 10
    ]);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';

$Autoritario ="";

        ob_start();


        $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                foreach($obj as $data)
                        {if($data['llave'] == 'Autoritario'){
                            for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++)
                                { echo "&#9733;"; 
                    }
                }
            }


        $Autoritario = ob_get_contents();//get the content

$Protector ="";

        ob_start();


        $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                foreach($obj as $data)
                        {if($data['llave'] == 'Protector '){
                            for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++)
                                { echo "&#9733;"; 
                    }
                }
            }


        $Protector = ob_get_contents();//get the content

$Participativo ="";

        ob_start();


        $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                foreach($obj as $data)
                        {if($data['llave'] == 'Participativo'){
                            for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++)
                                { echo "&#9733;"; 
                    }
                }
            }


        $Participativo = ob_get_contents();//get the content

$Negociador ="";

        ob_start();


        $obj = json_decode($myJSON,true);
                foreach($obj as $data)
                        {if($data['llave'] == 'Negociador'){
                            for($i=0;$i<$data['stars'];$i++)
                                { echo "&#9733;"; 
                    }
                }
            }


        $Negociador = ob_get_contents();//get the content

ob_end_clean();//erase the output buffer
$mpdf->WriteHTML($Autoritario);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($Protector);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($Participativo);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($Negociador);
$mpdf->Output();


?>
```

Hope you can help me please

Comment: I fixed it!! don't worry!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Carlos. While I'm glad that you fixed your issue, explaining how you fixed in an _answer_ will likely help anyone struggling with the same issue.